# Mongo lookup on null local field

Tags: mongodb

Is it possible to do a conditional look up depending on if the local field is null or not? I have a field that can be in 2 states. Either `null` (default value) or `{"item_key": "testkey"}`. I am trying to perform this lookup

```
{
   'from': 'items',
   'localField': 'item.item_key',
   'foreignField': '_id',
   'as': 'item'
}
```

The issue is that if the field `item` is null it returns a random document from the items collection.